# Assigning value to items in group based on other items in the group

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, group-by, pyspark

I'm trying to assign a value to each row in a group based on whether the input string is at the start of another string in the group. For example, "hello" is at the start of "hello world", so both of those are assigned the 'TOGETHER' value. 'goodbye' is not assigned a 'TOGETHER' value because it is not at the start of another string in the group.

```
input = [('1', 'hello'),('1', 'goodbye'),('1', 'hola'),('1', 'hi'),('1', 'hello world'),('1', 'hello world, goodbye'),('1', 'hello world, goodbye earth'),('2', 'bonjour'),('2', 'gracias'),('2','bonjour madame')]
spark.createDataFrame(input,['group','input']).show(10,truncate=False)
```

Here is the input:

[image]

Below is the desired output:

[image]

I am using pyspark, but if someone knows how to implement this in python, then I can work to translate it to pyspark.

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: @jarlh if someone knows how to do it in sql, I may be able to translate it to pyspark

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of code or data when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: An Sql version would be  kind of `case exists s2 : <check s1 is substring of s2 or s2 is substring of s1> then .. else .. end` Does it help?

Comment: @Serg the table is relatively big and there are many groups. Is there a more efficient way to check each string?

Comment: Sql is designed to deal with big tables. Indexes help to speed up queries. You may wish to create an index-like structure in your code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first we use a Window function to partition the DF by the '**group**' column. We group each of this groups again by the first word of each string of the '**input**' column. We do it by using the ***substring_index*** function. After creating the window function we are adding column to the DF, by counting the size of the each group we created by the window function -  checking whether the group has single row or more.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

w = Window.partitionBy(df.group, substring_index(df.input, ' ', 1))
df.withColumn('output', when(count('*').over(w) > 1, 'TOGETHER').otherwise('STAND ALONE'))
```